# How to open a QTableView from a QDialog

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtableview, qdialog

I have a QDialog displaying a login form. When user input the details and click on OK button I want to close the QDialog and open a QTableView instancied with login details inputed by the user.

I have tried to connect my OK button to a function that close my QDialog and show a QTableView but my QTableView appears half a second and the program ends with "Process finished with exit code 0"

Thanks !

```
    class TableViewGUI(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, user_id, mdp, profile):
    QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
    [...]

    class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
         super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
         [...]

    self.button.accepted.connect(self.openTableView)

    def openTableView(self):
         #data input by the user in the QDialog form
         id = self.input_id.text()
         password = self.input_password.text()
         profile = str(self.comboBox_profile.currentText())

         model = TableViewGUI(id, password, profile)
         view = QTableView()
         view.setModel(model)
         self.close() #Close the QDialog
         view.show() #Open the QTableView

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
     dialog = Dialog()
     dialog.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Okay your issue is that you do not have a properly structured program (that and this snippet you provide does not function fully so using it to try and help you is next to useless).   What you need is your  __Main__ (which you have) that handles the ApplicationThread and it calls MainGUI which handles the main GUI manager which in your case would not even be a GUI it would just display the Login Dialog window get the results from it then display the QTreeView Dialog window

Comment: Thanks Dennis, do you mean I should retrieve my login details from my main function, Create the QTableView from it and close the QDIalog ?
The problem will be how to launch QTableView on userclick if I do it from outisde the QDialog class

Comment: What am I doing wrong exactly in the code I provided ? Thanks

Comment: Cannot entirely say because you do not include enough code to run it -- to many missing elements. For instance: it references a button that you do not provide, TableViewGUI does not doing anything (a print statement is sufficient maybe) or you can take @GordonAitchJay suggestion however I would strongly suggest you do this right rather than perpetuate your current design as it is not properly structured

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the `openTableView` method ends, the `model` and `view` objects are destroyed, because they are only within the scope of the method. Append `self.` in front of them, like so:

```
    def openTableView(self):
         #data input by the user in the QDialog form
         id = self.input_id.text()
         password = self.input_password.text()
         profile = str(self.comboBox_profile.currentText())

         self.model = TableViewGUI(id, password, profile)
         self.view = QTableView()
         self.view.setModel(self.model)
         self.close() #Close the QDialog
         self.view.show() #Open the QTableView
```

Comment: No worries! Btw, please accept my answer, as per [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks!